# Django how to create a tmp excel file and return it to the browser within the response

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

I have a process to build a tmp file and then return it to the browser in csv. Now i want to do the same but return a excel file.

So what i have for the csv is a view in django that does:

```
def export_wallet_view(request):

   tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
   with open(tmp.name, 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as fi:
        csv_headers = [
            'Id',
            'Name'        
        ]
        fi.write(';'.join(csv_headers))
        fi.write('\n')

        //here also i save the rows into the file

  response = FileResponse(open(tmp.name, 'rb'))
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="wallet.csv"'
  return response
```

So to convert it to excel i try to do something like this using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(tmp.name)
    
df.to_excel('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', sheet_name='new_sheet_name')
```

The problem is that this creates the excel in the server, and i would like to do something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(tmp.name)
    
df.to_excel('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', sheet_name='new_sheet_name') //this being a tmp file

response = FileResponse(open(tmp.name, 'rb')) //this should be the new excel tmp file
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="wallet.csv"'
return response
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe use `io.Bytes()` to create file-like object in memory instead of file on disk. It is popular method to send files generated in memory.

Comment: you should use `df.to_excel(tmp.name, ...)` instead of `df.to_excel('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', ...)`, Or `open('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', 'rb')` instead of `open(tmp.name, 'rb')`. OR you should use another `tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` to create another name

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem.

You should use the same `'pandas_to_excel.xlsx'` in both

```
df.to_excel('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', ...)

... open('pandas_to_excel.xlsx', 'rb')
```

or the same  `tmp.name` in both

```
df.to_excel(tmp.name, ...)

... open(tmp.name, 'rb')
```

You can even use again `NamedTemporaryFile()` to create new temporary name.

```
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

df.to_excel(tmp.name, ...)

... open(tmp.name, 'rb')
```

---

But popular method is to use `io.String()` or `io.Bytes()` to create file-like object in memory - without creating file on disk.

```
def export_wallet_view(request):

    csv_headers = ['Id', 'Name']

    file_like_object = io.Bytes()
    
    file_like_object.write(';'.join(csv_headers).encode('utf-8-sig'))
    file_like_object.write('\n'.encode('utf-8-sig'))    
    file_like_object.write('other rows'.encode('utf-8-sig'))
    
    file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file

    response = FileResponse(file_like_object)
    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="wallet.csv"'
  
    return response
```

For excel it could be something like this. I use `io.String()` to read `csv` directly to `pandas`, and later I use `io.Bytes()` to create file-like object with excel data.

```
def export_wallet_view(request):

    csv_headers = ['Id', 'Name']
    
    text = ';'.join(csv_headers)
    text += '\n'
    text += 'other rows'

    df = pd.read_csv(io.String(text))
    
    file_like_object = io.Bytes()
    df.to_excel(file_like_object)

    file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file

    response = FileResponse(file_like_object)
    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="pandas_to_excel.xlsx"'
  
    return response
```